# Powershell Read a file and compare content

Tags: powershell

Have a problem  which seems to be to simple, but I can not crack.

I have 3 Files with a content of Usernames. I want to see which users match in File1 and  File2/File3. I would then write the users that match, into another file.

The problem is my if statement, it doesnt give me any values back / its never true. If I look for a random user that is in File 1 `if (User -in $MDM_USER) {Add-Content "C:\temp\MDM\USER_without_VPN.txt"}` " its working, but not as a $file variable.

Even if there is another way to get the same result, I would really appreciate if somebody could tell me what my mistake is.

```
$VPN_USER = Get-Content "C:\temp\MDM\Alle Benutzer mit VPN.txt"
$IT_USER = Get-Content "C:\temp\MDM\Alle_IT_Benutzer.txt"
$MDM_USER = Get-Content "C:\temp\MDM\alle_MDM-ios_user.txt"

foreach ($file in $IT_USER)
{
if ($file -in $MDM_USER) {Add-Content "C:\temp\MDM\IT_USER_with_VPN.txt"} 
}
```

Comment: To compare two objects in Powershell you can use [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: You have extra `{}` in your `if` statement. That means you have a script block that is not being called..so nothing happens to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-7.1) seems like an easier solution:

```
# it.txt users
user4
user5
user6
user2
user3

# vpn.txt users
user1
user2
user3

# mdm.txt users
user1
user5
user7
user3
user10

$it_users = Get-Content it.txt
$vpn_users = Get-Content vpn.txt
$mdm_users = Get-Content mdm.txt

Compare-Object $it_users $vpn_users -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru |
    Set-Content it_and_vpn.txt

Compare-Object $it_users $mdm_users -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru |
    Set-Content it_and_mdm.txt
```

**Results:**

```
PS> Get-Content it_and_mdm.txt
user5
user3

PS> Get-Content it_and_vpn.txt
user2
user3
```

**Explanation:**

By default, `Compare-Object` outputs differences between the reference and difference objects. You must use `-IncludeEqual` and `-ExcludeDifferent` in Windows PowerShell to only see equal objects from both lists. `-PassThru` outputs just the input objects (the compared objects) instead of the custom object typically created by `Compare-Object`.

---

Your logic seems correct with your approach. However, you have an extra set of `{}` around the `Add-Content` command. This creates a script block, and you did not call that script block, which results in `Add-Content` never being called. See below for an example of the behavior.

```
PS> { Get-Content vpn.txt } # Only outputs script block contents as a string
 Get-Content vpn.txt

PS> & { Get-Content vpn.txt } # & calls the script block
user1
user2
user3
```